# Do you violate any law/patent/license if you implement a open source processor for ARM ISA?

Tags: open-source, arm

I am considering an HDL implementation of the [ARM Instruction Set Architecture](http://morrow.ece.wisc.edu/ECE353/arm7tdmi_instruction_set_reference.pdf) as an open source project as part of course project and suport it with the gcc compiler/ [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). Will I be violating any law/patent/license by implementing any ARM ISA and distributing the source as an [open core](http://opencores.org/) ?

Comment: You probably will violate something, ARM have lawyers.

Comment: The original intent of *patents* was to share information **and** protect the patent holders financial rights.  Contrast [patent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent) with [trade secret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_secret); A *patent* lets someone disclose intellectual information while still protecting the idea.  So at least in some places, if you aren't selling anything, you aren't violating a patent.  Of course, I am not a lawyer and I **hope** no one here is.  You could contact ARM and explain to them.  They may grant you permission; safer than SO legal advice.

Comment: Maybe you should consider a free [OpenCore or1K](http://opencores.org/or1k/) to implement instead....

Answer (score 3):

Arm Ltd has at least 706 US Patents ([search)](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=0&f=S&l=50&d=PTXT&Query=AN/%22arm%20limited%22).  While ISAs are generally not protected, ISA implementations most certainly are, so you will need to ensure that your implementation does not violate any of Arm's patents.